# multiple MSP's for same org in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, msi-patch

Can I use multiple MSP's for same org. it was given like

"In some cases an organization may require multiple membership groups — for example, where channels are used to perform very different business functions between organizations. In these cases it makes sense to have multiple MSPs and name them accordingly, e.g., ORG2-MSP-NATIONAL and ORG2-MSP-GOVERNMENT, reflecting the different membership roots of trust within ORG2 in the NATIONAL sales channel compared to the GOVERNMENT regulatory channel."

in https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/membership/membership.html .

what does this mean ?